# Cakephp using Set class to fetch data with key starting at zero

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm using Set class of Cakephp to format the find returned array but cannot seem to find a way to get the counter starting at zero and auto-increment for array keys so it is like

```
[0] => 3
[1] => 6
[2] => 12
```

I'm currently using below query to get the data from my HasAndBelongsToMany table.

```
$interest_ids = Set::combine($this->User->Interestsub->find('threaded', array
                (
                    'conditions' => array
                    (
                        'Interestsub.name' => $interests
                    ),
                    //'fields' => array('Interestsub.id'),
                    'recursive' => -1
                )
            ),
            '{n}.Interestsub.id',
            '{n}.Interestsub.id'
            );
```

The reason why I need this is that I'm currently trying to get the returned array as part of bigger parent array preparing to be saved for SaveAll function. To be formatted properly, I need below nested array coming out:

```
[0] => Array
(
     [interestssub_id] => 12
     [user_id] => 2
)
[1] => Array
(
     [interestssub_id] => 22
     [user_id] => 2
)
[2] => Array
(
     [interestssub_id] => 32
     [user_id] => 2
)
```

Is there a way we can use Combine class to format the returned array like above?

Comment: If the only aspect of the output you need to change is the array indices, you can use `$new_array = array_values($old_array);` to reindex starting at 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no real reason to use the `Set` class in this case. Just use good old fashioned php:

```
$threaded = $this->User->Interestsub->find('threaded', array(
  'conditions' => array(
    'Interestsub.name' => $interests
  ),
  'recursive' => -1
));

$interest_ids = array();
foreach ($threaded as $thread) {
  $interest_ids[] = array(
    'interestssub_id' => $thread['Interestsub.id'],
    'interestssub_id' => $thread['Interestsub.user_id']
  );
}
```